# Issues with Youtube API Google Analytics tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, youtube-api, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to implement the following code in a Custom Html tag (GTM). This should track actions on Youtube video (play, pause, end). It seems the 'onPlayerStateChange' function is not called: the alerts are not triggered.

```
<body>
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>!function(e,t,a,n,g){e[n]=e[n]||[],e[n].push({"gtm.start":(new Date).getTime(),event:"gtm.js"});var m=t.getElementsByTagName(a)[0],r=t.createElement(a),s="dataLayer"!=n?"&l="+n:"";r.async=!0,r.src="//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id="+g+s,m.parentNode.insertBefore(r,m)}(window,document,"script","dataLayer","GTM-XXXXXX");</script> 

<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XVxBWa4KB9o?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://xxxxx&rel=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&autohide=1&html5=1" class="js-iframe" data-type="tvc" frameborder="0" width="900" height="520" allowfullscreen></iframe>

//This script is included in a GTM Custom Html Tag.
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $("iframe[data-type=tvc]").attr("id", "tvc");
    });

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(event) {
   player = new YT.Player('tvc', {
   events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
   });
}

var pauseFlag = false;

function onPlayerReady(event) {
   }

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        alert("play OK");
        dataLayer.push({'event':'movie', 'eventCat':'Video', 'eventAction': 'Play'});
        pauseFlag = true;
        }

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED && pauseFlag) {
        alert("Pause OK");
        dataLayer.push({'event':'movie', 'eventCat':'Video', 'eventAction': 'Pause'});
        pauseFlag = false;
        }

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        alert("End OK");
        dataLayer.push({'event':'movie', 'eventCat':'Video', 'eventAction': 'End'});
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: _"I'm trying to implement the following code  in a Custom Html tag"_ - this is a complete HTML page including the Tag Manager code itself. Are your really trying to put this into a tag management tag ?

Comment: Nope sure only the script is included in the Custom Html tag. I displayed the body page for the <iframe> tag.